# Sequelize - Associate and select from foreign tables

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, sequelize.js

## I created 3 SQL tables using `Sequalize`, the schemas are shown below:

### `Loans`

- id: `DataTypes.INTEGER`,
- book_id: `DataTypes.INTEGER`,
- patron_id: `DataTypes.INTEGER`,
- loaned_on: `DataTypes.DATE`,
- return_by: `DataTypes.DATE`,
- returned_on: `DataTypes.DATE`

### `Books`

- id: `DataTypes.INTEGER`,
- title: `DataTypes.STRING`,
- author: `DataTypes.STRING`,
- genre: `DataTypes.STRING`,
- first_published: `DataTypes.INTEGER`

### `Patrons`

- id: `DataTypes.INTEGER`,
- first_name: `DataTypes.STRING`,
- last_name: `DataTypes.STRING`,
- address: `DataTypes.STRING`,
- email: `DataTypes.STRING`,
- library_id: `DataTypes.STRING`,
- zip_code: `DataTypes.INTEGER`

## My goal is to query the `Loans` table using `Sequalize`, the `SQLite` query produced by `Sequalize` should looks like this:

```
SELECT 
book.title AS book, 
patron.first_name||' '||patron.last_name AS patron, 
loaned_on, 
return_by, 
returned_on 
FROM loans 
JOIN books ON loans.book_id=books.id 
JOIN patrons ON loans.patron_id=patrons.id
```

## Here is my attempt:

```
// Datebase relations
books.hasMany(loans, {
  foreignKey: 'book_id'
});
loans.belongsTo(books, {
  foreignKey: 'book_id'
});
patrons.hasMany(loans, {
  foreignKey: 'patron_id'
});
loans.belongsTo(patrons, {
  foreignKey: 'patron_id'
});

// All Loans page
router.get('/all_loans', function(req, res, next) {
  loans.findAll({
    attributes: [
      [Sequelize.col('book.title'), 'book'],
      [sequelize.literal("patron.first_name||' '||patron.last_name"), 'patron'],
      'loaned_on',
      'return_by',
      'returned_on'
    ],
    include: [books, patrons]
  }).then();

  res.render('all_loans', {
    title: "All Loans"
  });
});
```

## The code above generated this:

```
SELECT 
`loan`.`id`, 
`book`.`title` AS `book`, 
patron.first_name||' '||patron.last_name AS `patron`, 
`loan`.`loaned_on`, 
`loan`.`return_by`, 
`loan`.`returned_on`, 
`book`.`id` AS `book.id`, 
`book`.`title` AS `book.title`, 
`book`.`author` AS `book.author`, 
`book`.`genre` AS `book.genre`, 
`book`.`first_published` AS `book.first_published`, 
`book`.`createdAt` AS `book.createdAt`, 
`book`.`updatedAt` AS `book.updatedAt`, 
`patron`.`id` AS `patron.id`, 
`patron`.`first_name` AS `patron.first_name`, 
`patron`.`last_name` AS `patron.last_name`, 
`patron`.`address` AS `patron.address`, 
`patron`.`email` AS `patron.email`, 
`patron`.`library_id` AS `patron.library_id`, 
`patron`.`zip_code` AS `patron.zip_code`, 
`patron`.`createdAt` AS `patron.createdAt`, 
`patron`.`updatedAt` AS `patron.updatedAt` 
FROM `loans` AS `loan` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `books` AS `book` ON `loan`.`book_id` = `book`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `patrons` AS `patron` ON `loan`.`patron_id` = `patron`.`id`;
```

*The query pulls out all columns from `books` and `patrons` tables as well which I did not intend to specify.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I figured out how to fix my `Sequalize` code:

```
loans.findAll({
    attributes: [
      [Sequelize.col('book.title'), 'book_title'],
      [sequelize.literal("patron.first_name||' '||patron.last_name"), 'patron_name'],
      'loaned_on',
      'return_by',
      'returned_on'
    ],
    include: [{
      model: books,
      attributes: []
    }, {
      model: patrons,
      attributes: []
    }]
  }).then(results => {
    console.dir(results);
  });
```

It successfully produces the following SQLite code:

```
SELECT 
`loan`.`id`, 
`book`.`title` AS `book_title`, 
patron.first_name||' '||patron.last_name AS `patron_name`, 
`loan`.`loaned_on`, 
`loan`.`return_by`, 
`loan`.`returned_on` 
FROM `loans` AS `loan` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `books` AS `book` ON `loan`.`book_id` = `book`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `patrons` AS `patron` ON `loan`.`patron_id` = `patron`.`id`;
```

It seems I can not alias `book.title` as `book` or `patron.first_name||' '||patron.last_name` as `patron` because those aliases are used later on in the query.